# Error handling for bad values in JSON loading

Tags: python, json

I have a problem for loading JSON file using `json.load`.

```
with open(file) as json_file:
  self._metdata = json.load(json_file)
```

one the rows in the file is bad and gives this error:

```
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 515716 column 1 (char 24223047)
```

What I want it the `json.load` to ignore this value and keep loading the rest but I could not find a way to do it.
What I finally did is to read line by line and to check for error but its very slow.
Is there a better way to do it?
Thanks.

```
for file in [self._metadata_file_name, self._pharses_map_file_name]:
    with open(file) as json_file:
        for line in json_file:
            try:
                row = json.loads(line)
                if row:
                    if file == self._metadata_file_name:
                        self._metdata = {**self._metdata, **row}
                    else:
                        self._pharses_map = {**self._pharses_map, **row}
            except Exception as e:
                self._logger.log(message="Error pasring JSON " + line + ", for model: " + self._mode + ", file: " + self._metadata_file_name, error=str(e), metadata={"mode" : self._mode}, logType=self._logger.LOG_TYPE_ERROR)
```

Comment: `json.loads` ? with the `s` at the end ??

Comment: fixed, I edidted

Comment: Is this the only ill-formed json exception you care about? you could perform a ' -> " replacement before decoding the document. Or is it possible that you want to ignore all possible ill-formed sub-objects?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json.load` for loading a file. At line 515716, add double quote wrap the key. Hope to help you